# How to hide jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget by default and how it when needed?

Tags: jquery, multi-select, picklist

I am using [jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget) for one my my pick lists. Then problem is that I am having is when I use "display: none;" in the select This menu does not hide by default and it is always being displayed. 
I have a header file where I have this menu on all the pages but I want to hide it by default and show it when every I need it.

The problem is the "display: none;" is not hiding it. How can I get the MultiSelect Widget to not ignore the display: none?

thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried autoOpen true/false?

Comment: @TimSPQR thanks for your help but autoOpen will open the menu not make it invisible. I want to make it invisible by default and display it when needed.

Comment: I've never used the multiselect widget, but have extensively used the jQuery dialog. This page that I put together shows its use two ways (https://www.sites.google.com/site/timspqr/home/programs/javascript-code/jquery-dialog). The upper way is the standard way - the dialog opens when the inline code hits it. The bottom is more interesting. You declare the dialog with the uppercode, then with the lower two lines you can open(display) and close(hide) it very simply. There seems to be a consistency in jQuery, and I wonder if it is the same in the MultiSelect.

Answer (score 2):

`<select style="display:none;">` will not work. You have 2 options

assign a class to `<select>` and apply css-style to that class with `display:none`

or

wrap `<select></select>` with a `<div></div>` and apply the css-style `display:none` to that div